# How does a PDDL solver find a solution for a given problem?

Tags: planning, pddl

As far as I know, in PDDL, an environment is designed as well as the initial state described. When we describe the target state, the solver creates some sort of a graph. How is the graph built and what are the keys (keywords) in PDDL referring to?

I know that there are many flavours of PDDL, but let's go with the standard or the most common version of PDDL.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't really make sense: [PDDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language) is a *description language* that is used to formulate a problem. This description then is the *input* to a [planner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning_and_scheduling); how the planner arrives at the intended solution is not related to the PDDL description.

There are [a number of planning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning_and_scheduling#Algorithms_for_planning), and you can implement any of them to make use of a PDDL description. The output of the solver is a plan, which is usually an ordered sequence of actions, and a tree or graph structure might be a good way of capturing this.